# How to select on stored procedure with filter have more than 3 value

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures

I would like to know that how to select when using stored procedure with filter as combobox in website have more than 3 value

Exp: I would like to select match listing. and filter is "IsFinish" with value (All, Yes, No)

```
DECLARE @IsFinish INT -- 1: All 2: Yes 3: No

SELECT * FROM MATCH 
WHERE [Status] = ?
```

Status values: F: Finished C: Canceled L: Live N: Non-Live P:Pause X:(Close) Waiting Confirm

When select All the result will return all status.
When select Yes the result will return F & X.
When select No the result will return N, L, C, P.
I would like filter them by once select.
How can I do it?

Comment: I have tried to using where case when with 
where case when [status] IN ('L','N','F','X','C','P') then 0
   when [status] in ('F','X') THEN 1
   when [Status] IN ('L','N','C','P') THEN 2 END = @IsFinish
But I'm not feeling It look good.
I look forward to hearing from you in the nearest time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare Data

```
CREATE TABLE [Match] ([Status] CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY, [Wording] VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO [Match] ([Status], [Wording]) VALUES
    ('F', 'Finished'),
    ('C', 'Canceled'),
    ('L', 'Live'),
    ('N', 'Non-Live'),
    ('P', 'Pause'),
    ('X', '(Close) Waiting Confirm');
```

Prepare Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [FilterMatch] (@IsFinish INT = 1 /* 1: All (Default) 2: Yes 3: No */)
AS
  SELECT * FROM [Match] 
  WHERE @IsFinish = 1 OR 
       (@IsFinish = 2 AND [Status] In ('F','X')) OR
       (@IsFinish = 3 AND [Status] In ('N','L','C','P'));
```

Run

```
Exec FilterMatch;
Exec FilterMatch 2;
Exec FilterMatch @IsFinish = 3;
```

Comment: thank you for your help.! I was resolved!
Do stored procedure will run faster if we replace case when by charindex?

Comment: In the example above `[Status]` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, so equality condition would be most efficient. Should it be just a text field I doubt there would be any difference between `CASE WHEN` and `CHARINDEX`. In this particular case `CHARINDEX` probably would be shorter and clearer in code, but execution plan would be the same.

Comment: @YoungPhan  For short though **not** efficient `[Status] Like '[FX]'`, `[Status] Like '[NLCP]'` (or `[Status] NOT Like '[FX]'`) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL-Server* you can achieve It in following:

```
where [status] LIKE (case @IsFinish when 1 then  '%' end) or
      [status] = (case @IsFinish when 2 then  'F' end) or
      [status] = (case @IsFinish when 2 then  'X' end) or
      [status] = (case @IsFinish when 3 then  'N' end) or
      [status] = (case @IsFinish when 3 then  'L' end) or
      [status] = (case @IsFinish when 3 then  'C' end) or
      [status] = (case @IsFinish when 3 then  'P' end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IN and CASE and OR. Something like:

```
WHERE isFinish = 1 
  OR isFinish = 2 AND Status IN ('F','X')
  OR isFinish = 3 AND Status IN ('N','L','C','P')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to using where case when with

```
where case  when [status] IN ('L','N','F','X','C','P') then 0
            when [status] in ('F','X') THEN 1
            when [Status] IN ('L','N','C','P') THEN 2 END = @IsFinish
```

But I'm not feeling It look good.
I look forward to hearing from you in the nearest time.

Comment: Please don't use answers to add comments. Edit your question instead.